# Android pick specific contact from groups

Tags: android, contacts

hi guys  please i have contact phone number and contact name and contact id how can i determine to which group this contact belong if i have more than one group in my phone like favorites or family or friends

the code something like this i am not sure

```
  Cursor groupC = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+"= ?", new String[]{contactId}, null); 

                            while (groupC.moveToNext()) { 
                                String groupid =
                                    groupC.getString(groupC.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
                                Log.e("myTag", groupid); 
                                String grouptitle =
                                    groupC .getString(groupC.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE));
                                Log.e("myTag", grouptitle);
                            }
                            groupC.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you,

You can use the [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.html) table to query what group a particular contact is a member of. PERSON_ID is the ID of the contact, GROUP_ID matches the ID of the group.

In GroupMembership.PERSON_ID yo have the ID of the Person, and in the same table GroupMembership.GROUP_ID you have the ID of the group. You can retrieve the groups with the [ContactsContract.Groups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html).

Comment: thank you very much for your care but iam new in programming can you give me sample code please 
:)